# How to service/helper in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am a newcomer in Flask.

Now I am coding methods of routing like this:

```
@app.route("/categories")
def categories():
    return ""
```

How to create a service and global helper function(class) in Flask to use in each route methods? Should it be class? For example I need to write a common function `handleCategories()` that should be called in some route methods.

Comment: I usually put my common code in a separate `lib` directory and import it.

Comment: Do you util wrapper like a class with methods inside, or just methods in separate file?

Comment: Can you share own Flask ergonomic? I meant structure of projects, where services, helpers, models, controller, routing .etc

Comment: In Python there's rarely a reason to put things in a class unless they store state.

Comment: I won't make a class unless it is a common class that I want to use elsewhere. For your case just a function in a module would suffice.

Comment: Am I right that Python is more procedure language then Object oriented? I saw the more codes had written using procedure approach. Or this is lack of experience?

Comment: Python can be both Object-oriented or procedural. Sometimes carrying classes around is not possible between web views (not serializable), so I prefer functions in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from the Flask class if you want to structure your app into a class.

```
from flask import Flask

class MyFlaskApp(Flask):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(__name__)

        #You can add 'routes' with add_url_rule: which
        # is the same as @app.route("/categories")
        self.add_url_rule("/categories", "categories", self.categories)


    def categories(self):
        country = self.detect_country()
        if country == "eng":
            return "hello world"
        if country == "fra":
            return "bonjour monde"
        return ""


    def detect_country(self):
        #some code to detect users county
        return "eng"
```

To run the app, create an instance of it and call the `.run()` method on it.

```
app = MyFlaskApp()
app.run()
```

Using this method you would write your route logic as functions inside MyFlaskApp instead of using the `@app.route` decorator. You need to use `self.add_url_rule()` inside `.__init__()`, which is [the same function `@app.route` uses under the hood](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/app.py#L961).

Comment: Thank you, can I extend Flask life circle by my own function? I mean to call my function firstly somewhere in Flask before using route functions?

Comment: I meant the following case, when user comes to web site the system detects his country, then all code below(db queries) works based on detected country, Therefore, somewhere should be common function that works before all other  functons.

Comment: In general my question is how to write apps on Flask more Object oriented?

Comment: I've update the example a bit based on what you've said you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, should I write API methods inside `MyFlaskApp`? Using decorator?

Comment: Using this method you would write them as functions inside `MyFlaskApp`. If you want to expose the functions, instead of the `@app.route` decorator you need to use `self.add_url_rule()` inside `.__init__()`.

Comment: Don't write API method into `MyFlaskApp`, write them in proper routes with either `@app.route` or `Flask-Restful`'s `Resource` class (for better APIs...). Look at the example I gave below.

Answer (score 1):

**Synchronous service**

I usually have a `utils.py` file in my app folder where I put all the library functions.

You can even pass the Flask's `request` object to those functions so that you can access the HTTP request context (url, method, params, args, ...).

In your `app/utils.py`:

```
def handle_categories(request):
   args = request.args
   ...
   return result
```

Then, in your code:

```
from flask import request
from app.utils import handle_categories

@app.route("/categories")
def categories():
    result = handle_categories(request)
    return ""
```

**Asynchronous service**

Sometimes those functions in `app/utils.py` take too long for a standard http request (and you usually want requests to end fast to not bloat your webserver).

In that case you can run them asynchronously using Celery (`pip install celery`).

Let's rewrite the same function asynchronously in `app/tasks.py`. (Note that we'll have to drop the `request` object as a parameter because Celery task parameters have to be serializable to JSON.)

In `app/tasks.py`:

```
from celery import task

@task
def handle_categories(args):
   # do something with args
   return result
```

You can then call the tasks like this:

```
from app.tasks import handle_categories

@app.route("/categories")
def categories():
    result = handle_categories.delay(request.args)
    return ""
```

To run Celery tasks asynchronously, you need a config file and a worker:

`celeryapp.py`:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(__name__)
app.autodiscover_tasks(['app.tasks'])
```

Run the worker:

```
celery worker -A celeryapp.app
```

Comment: You'll need to install a message queue such as redis or rabbitmq as well.